# Copy List<A> to List<B> when both types share some or all properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have two similar classes in two different namespaces:

```
public class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create `List<B>` based on values in a `List<A>`.

I am doing it the old-fashioned way:

```
List<A> listA = new List<A>();
// load some values in listA.

List<B> listB = new List<B>();

foreach (var item in listA)
{
    B b = new B()
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Description = item.Description
    };
    listB.Add(b);
}
```

This is fine as long as there is a small number of properties in both classes, however, there are more than 15 properties in some classes.

Is there a better/efficient way to copy lists to avoid writing lengthy code?

Comment: http://automapper.org/

Comment: just use automapper, you can create a generic method to map peoperties from one class to another

Comment: If you use an Interface or Inheretance you can make your list type of the interface or abstract class. you'll lose no data and can just use `.AddRange`

Comment: Thanks guys, would AutoMapper work if some of the properties are different?

Comment: *"old-fashioned way"* still good. If you have a lot of properties with same names and types (e.g. DTOs), then consider to serialize/deserialize as another type using e.g. [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm):  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a))`. You may still have to copy *difference* manually.

Comment: Regarding automapper - yes you can tell it what property should match to what regardless of name. I guess you'd need to be careful if the property names were to change though.